# Confusion about using vertical grids in figma design

Tags: html, css, figma

So I just finished watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_w-iYiEXrl0) video about setting up a responsive grid for designing a webpage in figma

In this video it is suggested that you could use a vertical grid with each row being 8px high for making your vertical alignment more structured and consistent.
That means that the different elements in your grid will all have a height that is divisible by 8

Now I am just a bit confused because I usually just have the default height:auto set on my elements which as far as I know is the recommended way (since it is more responsive), but in order to make this work properly I would need to set fixed heights on my elements? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

It certainly seems like that's what the video is showing.  Designing with strict control over element heights isn't realistic though.  A user could increase their font size (vision impaired) or even overwrite the font (dyslexic).  Plus, there aren't just 3 screen sizes - there are potentially thousands. There's no way to be pixel-perfect in the element heights.

Rather, concern yourself with consistent padding & margins, and ensuring sibling components are sized the same.  That will create visual consistency.